# cannot implement pagination on datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

heres a snippet of my code (the rest is just column definitions and an initComplete implementation):

```
table = jq('#example').DataTable( {
             "select":{
                "style": "multi"
             },
             "processing": true,
             "serverSide": true,
             "lengthChange":true,
             "pageLength":10,
             "order":[[1,"asc"]],
             "dom": "Bfrtip",
             "ajax": '/'+localeCodeShort+'/umbrella/api/get-users',

  });
```

It's showing all the records (total is 103) on the draw instead of just 10. not sure why?

UPDATE

Here's my HTML:

```
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Email Address</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Email Address</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

And here's my JSON sample:

```
    {
  "draw": 1,
  "recordsTotal": 103,
  "recordsFiltered": 103,
  "data": [
    [
      "",
      "1",
      "Jonathan",
      "Reid",
      "reid@gmail.com",
      "1",
      ""          
    ],
    [
      "",
      "2",
      "Someone",
      "Foryou",
      "someadd@gmail.com",
      "1",
      ""
    ]
  ]
}
```

And here's my column definitions:

```
\"columnDefs\": [ 
                    {
                        \"orderable\":false,
                        \"className\":\"select-checkbox\",
                        \"targets\":0,
                        \"width\":\"5%\"
                    },
                    {
                        \"targets\": " . $dataTable -> actionCol . ",
                        \"data\": null,
                        \"defaultContent\": \"" . $btnHtml . "\"
                    },
                    {
                        \"targets\":-2,
                        \"className\":\"select-status\",
                        \"searchable\":true
                    },
                    ],
```

Also, im returning all 103 records currently

Answer (score 0):

Do check your html table. One thing on data table is that, the no of column of table header must be similar to column of table body. If you skip a column, the pagination won't work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the "paging" variable to true?

```
table = jq('#example').DataTable( {
     "select":{
        "style": "multi"
     },
     "processing": true,
     "serverSide": true,
     "lengthChange":true,
     "paging":true,
     "pageLength":10,
     "order":[[1,"asc"]],
     "dom": "Bfrtip",
     "ajax": '/'+localeCodeShort+'/umbrella/api/get-users',
});
```